# jQuery / ajax upload image and save to folder

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

**UPDATE CODE BELOW**

I found some code that is able to upload an image and display its thumbnail. However, I would like to save the images to a particular folder as well.

What jQuery code or ajax code can I use to save the original image to a folder of my choice?

Here is the live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dn9Sr/2/

Here is the full code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<style>
.input-file-row-1:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.input-file-row-1{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 25px;
    position: relative;
}

#preview_image {
  display: none;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 2px 0px 0px 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.upload-file-container { 
    position: relative; 
    width: 100px; 
    height: 137px; 
    overflow: hidden;   
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/AeUEdJb.png) top center no-repeat;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 23px;
} 

.upload-file-container-text{
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #719d2b;
    line-height: 17px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    position: absolute; 
    left: 0; 
    bottom: 0; 
    width: 100px; 
    height: 35px;
}

.upload-file-container-text > span{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #719d2b;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.one_opacity_0 {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 1px;
  float: left;
}
</style>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

   function readURL(input, target) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            var image_target = $(target);
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                image_target.attr('src', e.target.result).show();
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
         }
     }

    $("#patient_pic").live("change",function(){
        readURL(this, "#preview_image")
    });

});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<form name="" method="post" action="#" class="feedback-form-1">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="input-file-row-1">
            <div class="upload-file-container">
                <img id="preview_image" src="#" alt="" />
                <div class="upload-file-container-text">
                    <div class = 'one_opacity_0'>
                        <input type="file" id="patient_pic" label = "add" />
                    </div>
                    <span> Add Photo </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

UPDATE: I think I am on the right track. I am close but I don't know what data to send from the jQuery. I added a php scrit and its getting a call back as success but I am not sending the right var. I think if I just send the right val I can get it. 
CODE:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

   function readURL(input, target) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            var image_target = $(target);
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                image_target.attr('src', e.target.result).show();


                 $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: 'theUpload.php',
            data: input.files[0],
            success:function(data){
                console.log("success");
                console.log(data);
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function(data){
                console.log("error");
                console.log(data);
            }
        });



            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);








         }
     }

    $("#patient_pic").live("change",function(){
        readURL(this, "#preview_image")
    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 18):

Try this one.

Script:

```
function uploadFile(){
  var input = document.getElementById("file");
  file = input.files[0];
  if(file != undefined){
    formData= new FormData();
    if(!!file.type.match(/image.*/)){
      formData.append("image", file);
      $.ajax({
        url: "upload.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(data){
            alert('success');
        }
      });
    }else{
      alert('Not a valid image!');
    }
  }else{
    alert('Input something!');
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" id="file" />
    <button onclick="uploadFile();">Upload</button>
</body>
</html>
```

upload.php:

```
<?php
$dir = "image/";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $dir. $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

John's answer is good but file = input.files[0] doesn't work for me

```
file = input[0].files[0]
```

works.

Answer (score 1):

You need a server side language to store the uploaded image to specified folder. PHP is one of them, so I highly recommend to take a look of it.

AJAX is just for executing server side calls without refreshing the page.

Comment: Ok, I am able to use php as well.

Comment: I am sure there is some ajax code that can upload to a php script with the info it has right?

Comment: That's correct.. With that AJAX call you're referring to that PHP script you've made. The best option would be to use jQuery with the AJAX calls. You can see more information at http://www.jquery.com

Comment: I think I am close: data: input.files[0], is the line I am having issues with. The ajax seems to be working but I am not sending the right var.