# if (!empty($_POST)) store the uploaded file path and the user inputs

Tags: php, mysql

I am newbie on coding and I am trying to make a page where a user can upload a file and submit some info whenever he wants(during the uploading process or after). When he uploads a track I am setting a new name for the file first and then I move that file to a destination. Code is below;

```
if (isset($_FILES["img"]["name"]) && $_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"] != "") {
    ...
    $moveFileTo = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "test/$new_file_name"); 
    }
```

Next I have the following code where if the user press the save button in the form, while the file is still uploading or not, his inputs will be stored in my database along with the file path. If he doesn't press the save button then I store only the file path to the database so user can be able to submit the details later on. So I am using this code:

```
if (!empty($_POST["description"])) {
    ...store into database what user submited along with the file path from the first if statement....    
} else {  
    ...store only the file path...
}
```

Firstly is my approach correct? 
Where I am very stuck is that let's assume user refresh the page or navigates away. I know the file will not be uploaded but the file path will be stored in the database because my else statement stores the file path right?
Is there also a way to keep the file uploading even if user moves to another part of the site and if yes how can I achieve that?
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to use jquery or ajax to load the php page so that the image will be uploaded to. Look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398731/jquery-ajax-upload-image-and-save-to-folder

Comment: i checked but it doesn't answer to my question/problem.

Comment: ok. i recommend looking at this. I know this helped me a lot. Download it and see how it works. You will be doing an action when you upload a file and the file will be displayed. Thats how you know it has already been uploaden en temp stored. https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/